Subtotal calculation Script with multiple check boxes
I am creating a PDF document that adds up different fields by checkbox/radio button. Each checkbox/radio button has been assigned an export value. I am attempting to use another field to add all these checkboxes up based on if they are checked or not. Now, i understand PDF has an easier way to do this, but i want to do it a more sophisticated way if you will, and train my brain to learn more Javascript.
Here is what i have tried.
var nSubTotal = 0;
var nButton1 = this.getField("Button1").value;
   if (nButton1 != "Off"){
   event.value = nSubTotal + 20.00;
   } else {
   event.value = nSubTotal;
   }


var nButton2 = this.getField("Button2").value;
   if(nButton2 != "Off"){
       event.value = nSubTotal + 20.00;
    } else {
       event.value = nSubTotal;
    }


var nButton3 = this.getField("Button3").value;
   if(nButton3 != "Off"){
       event.value = nSubTotal + 40.00;
    } else {
       event.value = nSubTotal;
    }


var nButton4 = this.getField("Button4").value;
   if(nButton4 != "Off"){
       event.value = nSubTotal + 45.84;
    } else {
       event.value = nSubTotal;
    }


var nEay = Number(this.getField("EAY").valueAsString);
   if(nEay >= "0"){
       event.value = nSubTotal + nEay;
    } else {
       event.value = nSubTotal;
    }


var nButton6 = this.getField("Button6").value;
   if(nButton6 != "Off"){
       event.value = nSubTotal + 15.30;
    } else {
       event.value = nSubTotal;
    }


var nButton7 = this.getField("Button7").value;
   if(nButton7 != "Off"){
       event.value = nSubTotal - 15.30;
    } else {
       event.value = nSubTotal;
    }


var nButton8 = this.getField("Button8").value;
   if(nButton8 != "Off"){
       event.value = nSubTotal + 85.00;
    } else {
       event.value = nSubTotal;
    }


var nTRMC = Number(this.getField("TRMC").valueAsString);
var nTSO = Number(this.getField("TSO").valueAsString);


var Total = nSubTotal + nTRMC + nTSO;


event.value = Total;

I have researched and now understand that the script will only read the last else/if statement. How can i fix this?

event.value += nSubTotal maybe? don't forget to initialize event.value = 0 first
